# Assigning Macro to Button on AutoCAD

Tags: vba, button, autocad

I am trying to assign a button to my macro but it just won't budge , i've saved my macro as a .dvb file (Project.dvb) the code is on "Module2" and my Subname is "FCI", so here is my string "**^C^C_-vbarun;Project.dvb!Module2.FCI**". But it keeps on returning as "Macro not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not load the DVB? Type `VBAMAN` to verify the file is loaded. You may also want to use this instead:

`^C^C-vbarun;FCI;`